# Android: Getting Drawable from URL not working for .jpg, only works for .png

Tags: android, url, png, jpeg, drawable

I am working on and Android app that pulls a picture from an internet page (specifically xckd.com).  I have it working wonderfully using code of this basic form (see below)

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView;
    URL url = new URL(address);
    InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
    iv.setImageDrawable(d)
```

I noticed when I was viewing some of their older comics the image would not show (but I was scraping the other information from the page properly so I know the url is correct).   I determined that this result only occurs when the image is a .jpg file but works perfectly when it is a .png

I have Googled around plenty and I can't figure out why this is, is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: Define "would not show" -- crash? something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare:  no it just runs fine but where the picture should be is nothing but the padding space defined around the ImageView, not even a black box of the right size.   The picture title and description still load fine and I can advance to a new image (that is png) without error.

Comment: No it just doesn't display any image but everything else is normal, even the image title (so I know the link is ok).   There is nothing there but the padding of the ImageView.   (Sorry if this double posted, my 3G is crap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066. Using FlushedInputStream solves it.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer, not sure how you found this question 3 months after.